# In drupal 6, problems uploading images

Tags: image, drupal

I have the image module enabled, 
I have the file system path set at sites/default/files (works for attaching items including images) and the temporary directory as /tmp, download method Public

In site config: 
image is the default image path
images/image attach I have image attach enabled (although I don't really understand this)

In content management Profile I have Attach images enabled (and attachments enabled) and it uses the Image Attach module form

When I try to add a picture to my profile I get:

```
The selected file /tmp/xxx.gif could not be uploaded, because the destination /picture-131.gif is not properly configured.
Failed to upload the picture image; the directory doesn't exist or is not writable.
```

When I go to profile and try to upload a picture I get 
"The selected file could not be copied, because no file by that name exists. Please check that you supplied the correct filename." (I did supply one)

I see it in the list of existing images though and if I try to use that I only see 'no photo'

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the system to confirm that the directory permissions/ownership are correct?

Comment: Yes, I even made them 777 to test (and then changes them back to something more secure)

Comment: Also make sure the owner and group are set correctly for the user apache is running as.  You can find out the user apache is running as with `ps aux | grep apache` then use `chown` to properly set it recursively on `sites/default/files`.  I believe by default the owner and group are typically `www-data`.